# Determine whether XBOX 360 is on

Tags: networking

I want to determine in close to real-time (up to 5s lag would be OK) when my XBOX 360 is switched on or off over the network. The XBOX gets a static IP address which I know.

However the XBOX seems to be very much like a black hole in that it does not respond to pings and seems to have no ports open all the time (TCP 1029 is open when in XBOX Home, but not when actually playing a game).

What other ways could there be to find out whether the XBOX is online?

Comment: Can't it be rooted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use something like [arping](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/arping/) which will send an arp request to the specified ip address and wait for an answer. As [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) is required for Ethernet you should be able to check if the Xbox is online.

As your title and the question differ a little bit, you say you want to get a notification if your Xbox is switched on/off there may be another solution. The Xbox may send some ARP requests on startup to determine if the IP Address is available. If you are now using something like [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) or tcpdump you should be able to filter/react on these packets. But determine when the Xbox is switched off will probably take regularly checking if the Xbox is still online.

If you want a solution which does not require root permissions you can basically try to simulate `arping`:

1. Ensure the mac address is not listed in `ip neigh show` or `arp -an`
2. Try to connect to the Xbox, e.g. by connecting to an arbitrary port or via ping. It doesn't matter what you try as long as you try to directly communicate with the Xbox.
3. Check if the mac address is listed in `ip neigh show` or `arp -an`. If it is listed it means some device is responding to the specified IP address.

Comment: Thanks, using ```sudo arping -c1 -f -w1 <ip address>``` works great. The only downside is that now I need root permissions in my script. If no other answer turns up that doesn't need root permissions I'll accept this one.

Comment: Small remark: They're called Ethernet *packets* not *packages*. @MikaFischer: You can configure `sudo` to accept the `arping` command from a single user without prompting for a password, but that would be off topic for this question.

Comment: @jippie thanks :/ feel free to edit/fix the post, i changed it to packets

Comment: @jippie: Thanks, I already did it that way. But it's still a bit inelegant...

Comment: @MikaFischer you can try to check it with `nmap -sn` or if you have an older version of nmap try `nmap -sP`

Comment: I'm not allowed to change only three characters in an answer ;o)

Comment: @jippie as i also have to enter more characters for this comment :-(

Comment: @UlrichDangel: ```nmap -sn``` always shows the host as down. I also played with the other ```-P``` options and the ones that need root generally work (```-PU```, ```-PY```, ```-PE```). The others always show the host as down, except ```-P0``` which strangely always shows it as up...

Comment: @MikaFischer does it help if you run `nmap -sn` with root privileges?

Comment: @UlrichDangel: Yes, when running as root, ```nmap -sn``` alone also works fine.

Comment: @MikaFischer ok added the non root method (simulating arping)